# Ordering a list of regularly sampled 2D points on a curve

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, numpy, 2d

I need a function which orders 2D points based on their positions on the curve  such two points that are adjacent to each other on the curve are placed next to each other in the ordered list.

The length of the list is not limited, I am allowed to use only `math` module, I am using python 2.7.

"Regularly sampled" means the distance  between any two adjacent points is almost constant (have an 10**-3 epsilon value  example 0.0=0.001) for the given list of points.

So far i defined a function that consists of all the distances between all the points, but stucked. I though of using shortest path algorithm but in this case i need to use all the points. 
The code i have so far is

```
def dist(s):    
    return ((float(s[0][0])-s[1][0])**2.0+(float(s[0][1])-s[1][1])**2.0)**(1/2.)
def uz(x):
    if len(x)<=2:
        return []            
    else:
        x[1:2]=[]
        return [dist(x)]+uz(x)
def m(liste):
    return [dist(liste)]+uz(liste)
def alldist(liste):
    if len(liste)==2:
        return []
    else:
        k=[]
        for i in range(1,len(liste)):
            c=liste[(i-1):]
            k.append(m(c))
    print k
```

One of the 2 possible ordering is sufficient. 
I'd prefer help in algorithm, but code is also welcomed.

Thanks in advance!!!

sample input:

```
[[2.4492935982947064e-16, 4.0], 
 [2.0000000000000004, 3.4641016151377544], 
 [4.0, 0.0], 
 [-3.4641016151377539, 2.0000000000000013],
 [-1.9999999999999991, 3.4641016151377548], 
 [3.4641016151377548, 1.9999999999999998]]
```

output:

```
[[4.0, 0.0], 
 [3.4641016151377548, 1.9999999999999998], 
 [2.0000000000000004, 3.4641016151377544], 
 [2.4492935982947064e-16, 4.0], 
 [-1.9999999999999991, 3.4641016151377548], 
 [-3.4641016151377539, 2.0000000000000013]]
```

Comment: Can you post the code you have until now?

Comment: Voted to close the question. No one will solve that for you unless you tried to solve it first. We'll help you when you're stuck, but we'll not do the whole thing for you.

Comment: Of course i tried. Now i am writing the code i wrote so far

Comment: Without more constraints, the problem isn't well posed. Can the (presumed) curve self intersect? If not, does it maintain a minimum distance from itself? If not the latter, I suggest taking a step back, and try getting to your endgoal by a more elegant route.

Comment: Its not self intersect. The distance  between any two points (xi,yi) and (xj, yj) that are not adjacent to each other on the curve is going to be at least 1.5 times larger than the distance between any two adjacent points on the curve. The curve is open; i.e., the distance between the end points of the curve is at least 2 times larger than the distance between any two adjacent points on the curve.

Answer (score 1):

I succeed in doing this, but i am sure that it could be written in a better and shorter way.

```
import math
def rec_helper(x,u,constant):
    if x==[]:
            return u
    elif abs(x[0]-constant)<10**(-3):
        u=u+1
        return rec_helper(x[1:],u,constant)
    else:
        return rec_helper(x[1:],u,constant)

def distance(x,i,j):
    return math.sqrt((x[j][0]-x[i][0])**2+(x[j][1]-x[i][1])**2)
def alt(f,l,n,liste,constant):
    p=liste[n*l:(n*l)+l]
    for o in range(0,l):    
        if abs(p[o]-constant)<10**(-3):
            return f
        else:
            f=f+1
def order(x):
    t=x
    l=len(x)
    liste=[]
    for i in range(0,l):
        for j in range(0,l):
            liste=liste+[distance(x,i,j)]
    a=liste[0:l]
    a.sort()
    sabit=a[1]
    n=0
    uc_nokta_sira=0
    for h in range(0,l):
        if rec_helper(liste[h*l:h*l+l],uc_nokta_sira,constant)==1:
            n=h
    uc_nokta=t[n]
    sonlist=[uc_nokta]
    m=[]
    f=0
    g=0
    return son(f,l,n,liste,constant,sonlist,t,g)
def son(f,l,n,liste,constant,sonlist,t,g):
    f=0
    m=liste
    if len(sonlist)==1:
        g=n
        n=alt(f,l,n,liste,constant)
        f=0
        sonlist=sonlist+[t[n]]
        return son(f,l,n,liste,constant,sonlist,t,g)
    if len(sonlist)==l:
        return sonlist
    if sonlist[-1]==t[alt(f,l,n,liste,constant)]:
        m[(n*l)+alt(f,l,n,liste,constant)]=10**5
        k=alt(f,l,n,m,constant)
        g=n
        sonlist=sonlist+[t[n]]
        n=k
        return son(f,l,n,liste,constant,sonlist,t,g)
    else:       
            if sonlist[-1]==t[n]:
                g=n
                n=alt(f,l,n,liste,constant)
                return son(f,l,n,liste,constant,sonlist,t,g)
            else:
                sonlist=sonlist+[t[n]]
                g=n
                n=alt(f,l,n,liste,constant)
                return son(f,l,n,liste,constant,sonlist,t,g)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) you can achieve this with a considerable performance gain doing:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[2.4492935982947064e-16, 4.0], 
              [2.0000000000000004, 3.4641016151377544], 
              [4.0, 0.0],  
              [-3.4641016151377539, 2.0000000000000013],
              [-1.9999999999999991, 3.4641016151377548], 
              [3.4641016151377548, 1.9999999999999998]])
a = a[np.argsort(a[:,0])[::-1]]
#array([[  4.00000000e+00,   0.00000000e+00],
#       [  3.46410162e+00,   2.00000000e+00],
#       [  2.00000000e+00,   3.46410162e+00],
#       [  2.44929360e-16,   4.00000000e+00],
#       [ -2.00000000e+00,   3.46410162e+00],
#       [ -3.46410162e+00,   2.00000000e+00]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!, but it was a homework and i wasn't allowed to use NumPy.(only math module)